# Assigning Bootstrap popover to parent element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-popover

I am familiar with how Bootstrap's popover works and how to assign it to a specific container element. However, I have a situation where I have multiple elements generated by code and each of these elements may not have a specific pre-assigned ID. I have a created a fiddle of this situation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chicagosky/L7fjgwru/3/)

HTML code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Menu 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span>

    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu node-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="node-menu-item"> <a href="#" class="add-menu-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Child</a>

        </li>
        <li class="node-menu-item"> <a href="#" class="edit-menu-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit Node</a>

        </li>
        <li class="node-menu-item"> <a href="#" class="delete-menu-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete Node</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Menu 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span>

    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu node-menu" role="menu">
        <li class="node-menu-item"> <a href="#" class="add-menu-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Child</a>

        </li>
        <li class="node-menu-item"> <a href="#" class="edit-menu-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit Node</a>

        </li>
        <li class="node-menu-item"> <a href="#" class="delete-menu-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete Node</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="add-popover-content" class="hidden">
    <form role="form" method="post" action="/add" id="add-form" class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Department name" name="data[Department][name]" id="department-name">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
    <div id="validation-msg"></div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$('.add-menu-item').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    title: 'Add New Node',
    content: function () {
        return $("#add-popover-content").html();
    },
    container: function () {
        return $(this).parents('div');
    }
});
```

**Question**: How do I tell that the container should be the parent containing DIV? It seems like the container needs to be some specific named element. Your help is appreicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/L7fjgwru/10/

Have you tried removing the `container` function? The node seems to appear after removing the `container` function. You have to re-click the menu, however, before you see the node. Not sure if that is the desired result.

```
$('.add-menu-item').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    title: 'Add New Node',
    content: function () {
        return $("#add-popover-content").html();
    }
});
```

[image: Example output]

---

You can also make it so the menu doesn't close after clicking "Add Child" with the following code.

```
$('.dropdown-menu a.add-menu-item').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Example here:** http://jsfiddle.net/L7fjgwru/13/